# How to remove last duplicate row of each group by clolumn in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names like Date, Source1,etc.. How to remove only the last duplicate row from all the duplicates.

```
   Date         |     Source1
----------------|---------------------
3-Sep-11        |       JKY    
3-Sep-11        |       CYK
3-Sep-11        |       JKY
3-Sep-11        |       JKY
3-Sep-11        |       XYZ
4-Sep-11        |       JKY
4-Sep-11        |       CYK
```

I want to get the result as

```
   Date         |     Source1
----------------|---------------------
3-Sep-11        |       JKY    
3-Sep-11        |       CYK
3-Sep-11        |       JKY
3-Sep-11        |       XYZ
4-Sep-11        |       JKY
4-Sep-11        |       CYK
```

Comment: Anyone Please help me the above thing

Comment: Thank you.. Yossi for editing

Answer (score 0):

This does the thing.

```
s = """
   Date         |     Source1
----------------|---------------------
3-Sep-11        |       JKY    
3-Sep-11        |       CYK
3-Sep-11        |       JKY
3-Sep-11        |       JKY
3-Sep-11        |       XYZ
4-Sep-11        |       JKY
4-Sep-11        |       CYK 
"""

had_duplicate = False
stack = []

for e in reversed(s.splitlines()):
    if not had_duplicate and e in stack :
        had_duplicate = True
        continue
    stack.append(e)

print('\n'.join(reversed(stack)))
```

Comment: Thank you...doukremt But "s" is a DataFrame.

Comment: What difference does it make? You have access to the data as a string, don't you?